# making multiple functions more efficient react js

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, repeat

I have a code

```
export const a = () => {
     return (
           <WebView source = {{ uri: 'youtube1.com' }} />
     )
 }

export const b = () => {
     return (
           <WebView source = {{ uri: 'youtube2.com' }} />
     )
 }

 export const c = () => {
     return (
           <WebView source = {{ uri: 'youtube3.com' }} />
     )
 }
```

and I have about 10 of these.

What is a good way to reduce the repeating code and make code more efficient?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It'd be much better if you could provide more information about what you actual app does and how you are using these 10 functions in it. Thanks!

Comment: Without any context you can just pass an uri prop, see React docs for examples.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make this code more efficient by having a function like below

```js
export const webViewRenderer = (link) => {
    return (
        <Webview source={{ uri: link }} />
    )
}
```

And then import it in the file you want to use it, and use it in the following way

```js
const a = webViewRenderer('youtube1.com');
const b = webViewRenderer('youtube2.com');
const c = webViewRenderer('youtube.com');
```

You would then render a, b, and c respectively in your component's return statement.